# Javascript regExp Input Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input

This is my first post and i think the answer is very easy but i don't get it:

I (try) to build a shopify store but i have to make some modifications and here is the point at where i am stuck:

On my Product Page i want to inluce a `<input type=text>`, which is required, can only be Capital Letters and the length must min. be 1 and max. 10. I tried it with html5 pattern but it didn't worked. I read something, that if the shopify theme includes ajax, it just ignores the pattern and the required attribute (i don't know if this is true).

So i tried to make my own functions:

```
$('#dein-text').on("change textInput input", function(evt) {
    $(this).val(function (_, val) {
        return val.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

this just should return the string into capital letters.

```
function checkText() {
    var re = /(?=.*[A-Z]).{1,6}/;
    if(re.test($('#dein-text').val())) {
        $('#problem-bei-input').hide();
        $('.add', $product).removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {       
        $('#problem-bei-input').show();
        $('.add', $product).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

this function is executed at every change on the input form:
`$('#dein-text').on("change textInput input", checkText);`

This does not work, because it removes the disabled class if there is min. 1 letter (it does not check if there are more than 6) and if there is one capital letter (something like "HA11" does not add the (.disabled) class).

i hope i could describe what my problem is.

Thank you for your help!

edit: this is the .liquid code of the whole form:

https://codepen.io/shawdyy/pen/PmOPWy

(i hope you can see this on codepen, sry i am really new to the webdev thing)

Comment: post your html code too

Comment: Didn't `pattern="[A-Z]{1,10}"` work?

Comment: And if you need to match a string that only contains 1 to 10 uppercase ascii letters, you need `var re = /^[A-Z]{1,10}$/`.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Next time, please add the `@`+`username` in the comment when providing feedback to send a notification to that user. I posted an answer, please consider accepting since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
$('#my_id').on("change input", function(evt) {
    $(this).val(function (_, val) {
        return val.toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/, "").replace(/^([A-Z]{1,10}).*$/g, "$1");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

To only allow one to ten uppercase ASCII letters in the input field use the following HTML5 pattern:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{1,10}" title="Only 1 to 10 uppercase ASCII letters allowed!">
```

If you need to match a string that only contains 1 to 10 uppercase ASCII letters in plain JS, you need

```
 var re = /^[A-Z]{1,10}$/;
```

Note that start and end anchors (`^` / `$`) are added by the HTML5 automatIically when using the regex in the `pattern` attribute.